# How to split a string based on substring in a python dictionary limited by Class

Tags: class, dictionary, python-3.3

So I have a class

```
MyClass
    MyClass things
```

and in my main function I have a dictionary keeping track of each object and their properties like so:

```
dict = {
        'obj1':'[information string]'
        'obj2':'[information string2]'
         and so on
        }
```

And I'm trying to get a specific piece of information of the information string, and I would be able to do it if I was able to split the information string based on a substring, because the foramt of the information string is something like this:

```
'value1, value2, AlwaysHere: value3'
```

and if I was able to split the string based on 'AlwaysHere' -substring, I would be able to use value3 as I need to. Is there any other way to get value3 out of the nested dictionary or how can I split the string of information? I already tried:

```
type3 = dict[obj#].split("AlwaysHere ")
```

and it resulted in a failure with the message:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Comment: Do you actually have a `dict`? At the moment you're showing a *set*-literal (or are those `:`'s supposed to be outside the string?)... Also - what are you using that `dict` for - classes can already keep track of their own attributes etc... (eg: any reason that information shouldn't be an attribute of a class (instance) instead of in a dict?)

Comment: The reason why I can't (or at least know how to) use the attributes of the class to do this thing is because my code has to have a loop where user inputs Objects and their starting attributes, and "objname = input("put obj here" will just overwrite the previous entry/entries each loop. This is why I have dictionary - to save the values my Class function gives out for the user input.

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary definition is wrong
It should be

```
dict = {
        'obj1':'[information string]',
        'obj2':'[information string2]',
         and so on
        }
```

Also the string can be split in a manner you want, 
`"value1, value2, AlwaysHere: value3".split("AlwaysHere:")`

Will give

`['value1, value2, ', ' value3']`

Comment: Well, this is the dict I have, directly copied from my code after I've put a couple of inputs: {obj1: 'val1, val2, AlwaysHere: val3', obj2: 'val1, val2, AlwaysHere: val3'}

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little bit dumb, I'd failed at an earlier date at

```
MyDict[objname] = MyClass(stuff)
```

but now as I tried it a second time it worked like so, as I was able to call

```
MyDict[objname]
```

for the obj